# Elasticsearch NEST query nested object

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-query

I would like to retrieve a nested object from documents in my index called "userprofiles".

My UserProfile model:

public class UserProfileModel

```
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Oid { get; set; }
    public string Upn { get; set; }
    public List<SsoLink> FavoriteSsoLinks { get; set; } = new List<SsoLink>();
}
```

My SsoLink Model:

```
public class SsoLink
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Index creation:

```
PUT userprofiles
{
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "FavoriteSsoLinks" : {
                "type" : "object"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Query:

```
var searchResponse = _client.Search<UserProfileModel>(s => s
                .Index(_profileIndex)
                .Query(q=>q
                    .Term(t => t.Field(t => t.Oid).Value(oid)
                        )
                    )
                );
```

Right now it returns the documents, but the favoritelinks object is blank, however I see objects listed from Kibana. I must be missing something obvious, but having trouble figuring this out.

Here is an example of my data:

[image]

Comment: Query appears to be correct. Can you add a sample document from your index

Comment: Query is fine, I tried at my end. Could be the case the documents which you are searching for oid might not be having favoriteSsoLinks value. You should run {
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "oid": {
        "value": "VALUE"
      }
    }
  }
} and check value in kibana dev tools

Comment: Interesting, I am trying to find all the favoriteSsoLinks where oid = "someOID". How did you make your index?

Comment: I just created a sample sample document with object type and a text field and  my returned model has the object field. In  your case you can run the query in kibana dev tools to make sure "favoriteSsoLinks" has value(could be empty) or if you are using source filtering then you are mentioning this field

Comment: Ok, so when I search with dev tools 
GET userprofiles/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_id": {
        "value": "1-123-1234-1232-41234-12341"
      }
    }
  }
}
I can see the response, but in my code I don't get them favoriteSsoLinks back...

Comment: Where you able to find the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index creation example uses `"FavoriteSsoLinks"` as the property, but the Kibana screenshot uses `"favoriteSsoLinks"` starting with a lowercase `f` - which is correct? My suspicion is that property casing may be the issue, but would need to see the mapping in the index to know if this is correct.

The 7.x client is strict about property name casing in JSON, and by default uses camelcase property names to match to POCO property names. For example, by default

- `"favoriteSsoLinks"` in JSON will **be a match** for `FavoriteSsoLinks` POCO property
- `"FavoriteSsoLinks"` in JSON will **not be a match** for `FavoriteSsoLinks` POCO property

This behaviour can be changed with `DefaultFieldNameInferrer(Func<string, string>)` on `ConnectionSettings` for all properties, or on a property by property basis using attributes on properties such as `DataMemberAttribute` or `PropertyNameAttribute`, or using `DefaultMappingFor<T>` where `T` is the POCO type.